# Upload and attachement for phpmailer

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, security, file-upload

hello i starting an code to allow sending file via a form
i create an input file field

```
<input type="file" name="'.$field_name.'[]" accept="'.$values_field[0].'" id="'.$field_id.'" '.$placeholder.' aria-label="'.$field_label.'" class="inputfile '.$required.'" '.$uploadmode.' style="margin:0" maxuploads = 2 >
```

i create this code

```
//upload attachement
        $files = $jinput->files->get($formid);
        if (isset($files))
        {
            foreach($files as $attachements) {
                foreach ($attachements as $file){
                // Import filesystem libraries. Perhaps not necessary, but does not hurt.
                jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

                // Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc.
                $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

                // Set up the source and destination of the file
                $src = $file['tmp_name'];
                $dest = JPATH_SITE . DS . "tmp" . DS . $filename;
                    // TODO: Add security checks. FIle extension and size maybe using joomla rules

                    if (JFile::upload($src, $dest))
                        {
                    $mailer->addAttachment($dest);
                        } 
                    else
                        {
                        $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('FLEXI_FIELD_EMAIL_MESSAGE_SEND_ERROR'), 'error');
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        //Sendemail
        $send = $mailer->Send();

        //Message in front-end
        if ( $send !== true )
            {
                $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('FLEXI_FIELD_EMAIL_MESSAGE_SEND_ERROR'), 'error');
                //Deleting file
                if (is_file($dest)) {
                JFile::delete($dest);
                } 
            } else {
                // Message sending
                $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('FLEXI_FIELD_EMAIL_MESSAGE_SEND_SUCCESS'), 'message');
                //Deleting file
                if (is_file($dest)) {
                JFile::delete($dest);
                } 
            }
    }
```

i need some help for 2 questions,
how is the best way to check file extension for better security ? can i use (and how) the joomla rules (mime and size files)
what is the better solution for deleting files after sending without redo the foreach ??
thanks for any help !

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour]. The concern about reliably validating a file extension has been debated for years.  As I recall, the jury is still out.  You can research these discussion on Stackoverflow.

Comment: hello i realy search but i didn't fine a solution for 
- retrieve mime restriction and size of joomla config
- a good solution to delete file avec sending ...
thanks for link or helping

Comment: What file types were you thinking of whitelisting?  To get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34807483/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595623/2943403 , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37658/141885 , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/144880/141885

Comment: cool thanks i already find this => my question is more precise about joomla, its possible to find joomla rules ? (mime allowed, max-file size)

Comment: You might find some stuff in https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_Image useful. There's file upload code explained in the Site Helloworld Form section.

Comment: you mean  ```// do checks against Media configuration parameters
   $mediaHelper = new JHelperMedia;
   if (!$mediaHelper->canUpload($file))
   {
    // The file can't be uploaded - the helper class will have enqueued the error message
    return false;
   }```